# Background Subtraction for hand recognition in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to make a hand gesture recognition program using OpenCV's Background Subtraction method but I am facing the following problems, partial binary image of the hand, and getting a convexity defects error.

Before posting this question I did look up various posts here but none of those solutions worked for me perfectly.

1. Partial Binary Image Problem:
   I am using the MOG2 Background Subtraction method of OpenCV which seems to work better than the other methods but still I get a partial binary image of my hand as shown in the figure below. I have dilated the binary image to improve its result and used `medianBlur` for Noise cancellation but still I get the following result. My goal is to get a complete and continuous binary image of my hand and need help for how to do it.

Binary Image
[image]
Contours result from `approxPolyDP`
[image]
Contours result from `convexHull` and `approxPolyDP`
[image]

2. Convexity Defects Error: 
   For some reason I am getting the following error while trying to find the convexity defects.

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (hull.checkVector(1, CV_32S) > 2) in convexityDef
>   ects, file C:\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 1971
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>    what():  C:\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1971: error: (-215) hull.c
>   heckVector(1, CV_32S) > 2 in function convexityDefects

I have looked up in different places for finding a working solution but have been unsuccessful so far.

code

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int lH =0;
int lS =0;
int lV =0;
int uH = 180;
int uS = 255;
int uV = 255;

void filterImage(Mat &img)
{
Mat erodeElement  = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT,Size(2,2));
Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT,Size(5,5));

//erode(img,img,erodeElement);
dilate(img,img,dilateElement);
dilate(img,img,dilateElement);
}

int main()
{
Mat frame(600,600,CV_8UC3);
Mat fgMaskMog2(600,600,CV_8UC1);
Mat refinedimg(600,600,CV_8UC1);
namedWindow("frameOutput",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("Mog2Output",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("out",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 MOG2;
BackgroundSubtractorMOG MOG;

VideoCapture cap(0);

//contours variables
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;


while(1)
{
    cap>>frame;
    flip(frame,frame,1);

    MOG2(frame,fgMaskMog2);

    filterImage(fgMaskMog2);
    medianBlur(fgMaskMog2,fgMaskMog2,15);

    Canny(fgMaskMog2,refinedimg,50,200,3);
    findContours(refinedimg,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Point(0,0));
    vector<vector<Point> > hull(contours.size());
    vector<vector<int> > hulldf(contours.size());
    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
    vector<vector<Vec4i> > defects(contours.size());
    for(int j=0;j < contours.size();j++)
    {
        approxPolyDP(contours[j],contours_poly[j],5,true);
    }
    for(int k=0;k<contours.size();k++)
    {
        convexHull(contours_poly[k],hull[k],false);
        convexHull(contours_poly[k],hulldf[k],false);
        if(hulldf.size()>3)
        {
            convexityDefects(contours[k],hulldf[k],defects[k]);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
    {
        drawContours( frame, contours_poly, i, Scalar(0,255,0), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
        drawContours( frame, hull, i,Scalar(255,0,0),2,8, hierarchy,0,Point());
    }

    imshow("frameOutput",frame);
    imshow("Mog2Output",fgMaskMog2);
    imshow("out",refinedimg);

    int c = waitKey(31);
    if(c==27)
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate any other extra suggestions for improvement of my this program.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for HSV Solution? It is perfect for skin color detection and also remove the background of skin.

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html

That link helped when I was working on hand gesture recognition.

Another link for code:

http://www.andol.info/hci/1116.htm
http://answers.opencv.org/question/3300/skin-detection/

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the size of your structuring element in your `filterImage()` function, so that the binary fragments will be connected.
Also, try to apply `findContours()` directly on the binary image instead of the Canny-image.